# FabricJs Custom Attribute SVG strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, fabricjs

I want to add a custom attribute for each object in my canvas. I did that using:

```
fabric.Object.prototype.toObject = (function (toObject) {
    return function () {
        return fabric.util.object.extend(toObject.call(this), {
            zzz: this.zzz
        });
    };
})(fabric.Object.prototype.toObject);
```

After that I set my zzz property to 100 for each object:

```
fabric.Object.prototype.zzz = 100;
```

After this I put inside the canvas a text:

```
var text = new fabric.Text("time", {fill: '#999', zzz: 85, top: 50});
canvas.add(text);
```

And then I put inside a SVG (The svg is added by clicking a button [probably not important]):

```
fabric.loadSVGFromURL(link, function (objects, options) {
    var group = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
    group.set({
        ...,
        zzz: 88
    });
    canvas.add(group);
    canvas.renderAll();
});
```

Now If I do a `console.log(selectedObject.zzz);` I get 85 for text and 88 for SVG. Everything great. But ... If I do:

```
myjson = JSON.stringify(canvas);
console.log(myjson);
```

And load this Json and then `console.log(selectedObject.zzz);` I get the 85 for text and 100 for SVG. But the SVG doesn't have the zzz property in it (it has 100 because of `fabric.Object.prototype.zzz = 100`) but instead every path has the zzz property with value 100; (at first when the SVG had 88 the paths didn't have the zzz property inside).

Image with the SVG after json: (no zzz property)
[image: Pic 1]

Image with the SVG's paths after json: (zzz property for each path)

[image: Pic 2]

My question is how can I have property zzz in SVG after the Json and get after `console.log(selectedObject.zzz);` the 88 value? The property is lost somehow but I don't know why.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

if you want to stringify canvas and keep your custom attributes you must tell fabric to do so:

canvas.toJSON(['zzz'])